# Why am I getting this Error: Error 1215 Cannot add Foreign key constraint?

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys

I am working with three tables.

```
CREATE TABLE Unit(
AptNumber integer(4),
PopertyId integer(4),
RentalPrice integer(8),
Size varchar (20),
PRIMARY KEY (PopertyId, AptNumber),
FOREIGN KEY (PopertyId) REFERENCES Property (Id)
);


CREATE TABLE Customer(
Name varchar(15),
RenterId integer(6),
PRIMARY KEY(RenterId)
);
```

and

```
CREATE TABLE Rentals(
AptNumber integer(4),
RenterId integer(6),
StartDate varchar(8),
EndDate varchar(8),
PRIMARY KEY(AptNumber, RenterId),
FOREIGN KEY (AptNumber) REFERENCES Unit(AptNumber),
FOREIGN KEY (RenterId) REFERENCES Customer(RenterId)
);
```

When I try to create the third table, rentals, I receive the error message. ERROR 1215 (HY000): Cannot add foreign key constraint.

My keys match in data type and size, so I'm not sure what the problem is.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Where is your table Property?

Answer (score 1):

This is the problem:

```
FOREIGN KEY (AptNumber) REFERENCES Unit(AptNumber),
```

When you reference a parent column like Unit(AptNumber), that column must be the *first* column in a key in the referenced table.

But yours is the *second* column in Unit's primary key:

```
PRIMARY KEY (PopertyId, AptNumber),
```

Also, ideally the foreign key should reference the *whole* primary or unique key, so you're guaranteed that a row in the child table references exactly one row in the parent table.

Technically, InnoDB has a nonstandard feature that allows a foreign key to reference a subset of the columns of the parent's primary key, but that means your child row could reference more than one row in the parent table. That brings up a bunch of weird cases like what if you delete the row in the parent table? Best to avoid creating such foreign keys.

Answer (score 0):

Its better:

```
1.Create Main table first with Primary Key.
2.Create Foreign Key table without a constraints.
```

and so on....

Alter table tbl_foreign add contraints:

```
ALTER TABLE tbl_foreign 
ADD FOREIGN KEY (P_Id)
REFERENCES Persons(P_Id)
```

See this for [Alter](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_foreignkey.asp) table Constrains